# i have a error when start jsipster mvnw

Tags: jhipster

this is error text: I using windows an xampp server

> *****2017-05-31 14:33:41,401 **ERROR restartedMain o.s.b.SpringApplication:815 - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'**; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: E xception
>   thrown while building outbound endpoint at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   at
>   com.mgm.example.easysample.EasysampleApp.main(EasysampleApp.java:68)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException:
>   Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:122)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:55)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:125)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
>   ... 17 common frames omitted **Caused by:
>   org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to
>   zookeeper server within timeout: 10000** at
>   org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232) at
>   org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.(ZkClient.java:156) at
>   org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.(ZkClient.java:130) at
>   kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76) at
>   kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58) at
>   kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala) at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:169)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicsIfAutoCreateEnabledAndAdminUtilsPresent(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:109)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:60)
>   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:108)
>   ... 23 common frames omitted [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 01:30 min [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-05-31T14:33:42+04:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 66M/533M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ enter code here*****

Answer (score 0):

Based on the main error of `org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000`, you haven't started Zookeeper.  This is a requirement if you selected the Kafka option (see [JHipster's Kafka docs](https://jhipster.github.io/using-kafka/) for more info).

The first option is to use Docker.  JHipster provides docker-compose files for Zookeeper and Kafka in `src/main/docker/`. You can start them up by running:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/kafka.yml up -d
```

The second option is to manually set up and install Kafka and Zookeeper.